# AS3 Finding common values in Arrays

Tags: arrays, flash, actionscript-3

I'm struggling with something that shouldn't be too difficult but I can't figure it out I have a number of Arrays with different values and I want to find the common values all of the Arrays have, see example below:

```
        var arrayOne:Array      = ["1","2","3"];
        var arrayTwo:Array      = ["1","2","7"];
        var arrayThree:Array    = ["1","2","9","12"];

        _resultArray = ["1","2"];
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
///Returns common values between to arrays
function getCommonValues(array1:Array, array2:Array):Array
{
    var len1:int = array1.length;
    var len2:int = array2.length;
    var toReturn:Array = new Array();

    for(var i:int = 0; i < len1; i++){
        for(var n:int = 0; n < len2; n++){
            if(array1[i] == array2[n]){
                toReturn.push(array1[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
}
```

Then do something like:

```
var arrayOneAndTwo:Array = getCommonValues(arrayOne,arrayTwo);
var _resultArray:Array = getCommonValues(arrayOneAndTwo,arrayThree);
```

Optionally you can modify the function to include all three arrays in the comparison, which would be more efficient.

**Edit**

If you want to process an unknown amount of arrays you can add:

```
///Returns common values between X number of sub arrays
function getCommonValuesFromSubArrays(papaArray:Array):Array
{
    if(papaArray.length < 2){ return papaArray; }

    var toReturn:Array = papaArray[0];

    for(var a:int = 1; a < papaArray.length; a++){
        toReturn = getCommonValues(toReturn, papaArray[a]);
    }

    return toReturn;
}
```

Then something like:

```
var arr1:Array = ["one","two","three","four","five"];
var arr2:Array = ["one","two","five","six"];
var arr3:Array = ["one","two","three","four","five"];
var arr4:Array = ["one","two","three","four","five"];

var bigOlArray:Array = [arr1,arr2,arr3,arr4];

var _results:Array = getCommonValuesFromSubArrays(bigOlArray);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, is there an easy way to modify the function to accept any number of Arrays rather than a specified amount.

Comment: thanks this is great but what about if you have multiples of the same values? var arr1:Array = ["1","1","1","1","one","two","three","four","five"]; value "1" does count to the results?

Comment: @v1ru2 as-is the code would add "1" assuming both arrays have it, but if you did not want a chance of duplicate "1" values, you can easily check if the value already exists in `toReturn` before calling `toReturn.push(array1[i]);`

Comment: @ToddBFisher thanks will try this (but not sure i will be able to get it to work), i added a question here -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492636/as3-finding-common-values-in-arrays-but-with-multiple-array-values

Comment: @ToddBFisher i want the duplicate array values "1's" in arr1 to be counted not ignored?

Comment: @v1ru2 sounds like you want to find the most common value in an array, which is different than this question.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a function to concatenate all arrays, sort by numerical value, and collect all items that are available exactly as many times as the number of arrays that were passed in as parameters:

```
var arrayOne : Array = [ "1", "2", "3" ];
var arrayTwo : Array = [ "1", "2", "7" ];
var arrayThree : Array = [ "1", "2", "9", "12" ];
// you can pass in any number of Arrays
trace ( searchArraysForCommonItems ( arrayOne, arrayTwo, arrayThree ) ); // returns ["1", "2"]


function searchArraysForCommonItems ( ...args : * ) : Array
{
    var searchArray : Array = [];
    for each ( var arr:Array in args)
        searchArray = searchArray.concat ( arr );

    var resultArray : Array = [];
    var last : String;
    var times : int = 0;
    for each ( var str : String in searchArray.sort ( Array.NUMERIC ))
        if (last == str) times++;
        else
        {
            if (times == args.length) resultArray.push ( last );
            last = str;
            times = 1;
        }

    return resultArray;
}
```

Of course, you can (and should) use `Vector.<String>` instead of Array wherever possible to improve performance, but always remember that `Array.sort()` is a native function and *very* fast...

Answer (score 2):

I would use the Array.filter() Function to achieve this:

```
var _resultArray:Array = arrayOne.filter(
   function(item:String, index:int, arr:Array):Boolean
   {
      return (arrayTwo.indexOf(item) != -1 && arrayThree.indexOf(item));
   }
);
```

This will loop over arrayOne and return an array with the values that both appear also in arrayTwo and arrayThree.

Edit: And here is a function that will take any number of arrays and return the common values:

```
function getCommonValues(arrayOne:Array, ... arrays:Array):Array
{
    var _resultArray:Array = arrayOne.filter(
       function(item:String, index:int, arr:Array):Boolean
       {
          return arrays.every(
            function (a:Array, index2:int, arr2:Array):Boolean
            {
                return a.indexOf(item) != -1;
            }
          );
       }
    );
    return _resultArray;
}
```

Usage:

```
resultArray = getCommonValues(arrayOne, arrayTwo, arrayThree, arrayFour);
```

The function has another nested closure inside the first one, so might be a bit hard to understand, but I tested it, it works.

Comment: Wow I had to look at this for 15 mins to understand it, very clever solution!